# Setting a custom key property for CArrayDataProvider?

Tags: yii

I have:

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider ($items , 
  array(
    'pagination'=>array(
      'pageSize'=> 10,
  ),
));
```

And I render:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
  'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
  'itemView' => 'items',
  'summaryText' => '',
  'emptyText' => '
  ', 
));
```

Problem is it whines about the ID in the dataset. It wants it to be called "id". So I geT:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$id
C:\wamp\www\yii\web\CArrayDataProvider.php(108)
```

How can I change it so that it uses "itemid" instead of "id" as the column reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the data provider's [`keyField`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider#keyField-detail) property:

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider ($items , 
  array(
    'keyField' => 'itemid',
    'pagination'=>array(
      'pageSize'=> 10,
  ),
));
```